# Whats kind of relationship should I create ? One-To-One or One-To-Many?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am using MS-Access database.

I am trying to make relationship with two tables, Old Customer table having data and Newly added coupon table.

As my client want to introduce new concept of coupon, where customer come with coupon instead of giving cash.

I have inserted Coupon code in coupon table in bulk.

Now, I am confused about what kind of relationship I should create with these two tables ?

I have to consider the below things...

1. customer can give either cash or coupon.
2. IF customer show the coupon, there will be an entry in CouponID column 
   as well in cash column (to know the value of that coupon.)
3. The CouponID should be unique in the customer table,  Coupon Code should 
   not be repeated.

I am confused whether it should be one-To-One or One-To-Many ?

This image will help you to understand the problem. 
[image]

Comment: You are missing `Sale Order` table that will have fields: CouponID and CustomerID. So it is many-to-one as each customer can use several coupons on different orders and coupon can only be used by single customer. The problem with your current schema is that you don't have customerID on `Coupon` table, which would reflect the cardinality.

Comment: No Customer has to be treated as new every time, like customer in retailer shop.

Comment: In this case it is one-to-one

Comment: I am unable to make one to one relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I would not include "CouponID" in the customer table at all (nor "Cash" for that matter). The customer table models a customer, the coupon table models a coupon. 
You need another table to model the transaction:

[CustomerTransaction] 
id
date
customer_id
coupon_id

etc...

Every type of independent "thing" should be modeled by a discrete table. and "things" should be related to each other by other tables that create the 1:N relationship.

Comment: Ok, sounds logical... do you provide any link which I can see the transaction table ? I dont use MS-ACCESS usually.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship of customer to coupon is an optional (ie nullable) one-to-one; your data model looks good.

Some other comments:

- The table would be better named `sale` rather than `customer`, since if the same customer comes back again, there will be a new row (but with the same name)
- You could create a unique index on `couponID` that ignores nulls
- You could rename `Cash` to `Amount`; the amount is *either* "cash" *or* coupon - the `couponID` column tells you the *type* of the amount

To create a unique index that ignores nulls:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx1 ON customer (couponID) WITH IGNORE NULL;
```

Comment: Its fine if customer repeated... but whether I req. transaction table for this model ?

Comment: @user1650894 it is already a transaction model - ther's one row per sale. Consider adding a `timestamp DATETIME`` column